# How to display file which had already upload laravel 5.2?

Tags: laravel, file-upload, filepath, laravel-blade

I upload file in to my database and moved that file as same name in **documents** folder in a root path like below :)

```
public function store(PslCall $call,Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, $this->rules);
        $uploadDestinationPath = base_path() . '/documents/';
        $current_id = Document::where('call_id',$call->id)->count()+1;
        if ($request->hasFile('file'))
        {
            $file =$request->file;
            $fileName = $file->getClientOriginalName();
            $file->move($uploadDestinationPath, $call->id.'_'.$current_id.'_'.$fileName);
        }
        $input = $request->all();
        $input['file'] = $call->id.'_'.$current_id.'_'.$fileName;
        $input['call_id'] = $call->id;
        Auth::user()->documents()->create($input);
        return Redirect::route('calls.documents.index',$call->id)->with('message','You have successfully submitted');
    }
```

its works perfect now im display in my index page all the files like below :)

```
<td>{{strtoupper($document->title)}}</td>
<td><a href="{{ url('documents/'.$document->file) }}" target="_blank">{{$document->file}}</a></td>
```

now my route file i have route to display my file like this :

```
Route::get('documents/{file}',function() {
  return 'hi';
});
```

**here im getting hi output when i click** `<td><a href="{{ url('documents/'.$document->file) }}" target="_blank">{{$document->file}}</a></td>` **`this path`**

but i want know how to display file which i upload same file name ?

Comment: You question is not very clear. Do you want to show the content of the file? Do you want to start a download of the file?

Comment: i want open that file thatz all :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [documentation says](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/responses#file-responses) if you want to display the file content then you may use inside your route function something like:

```
return response()->file('pathToFile');
```

If download the file is what you want, then try to use instead:

```
return response()->download('pathToFile');
```